# HTML5 audio element with source being audio stored as varbinary bytes from database

Tags: javascript, c#, html, audio, asp.net-mvc-5

This is a normal audio player, but if i wanted my source to be audio stored in my database how would i go about achieving this ?

```
<audio controls="controls" autoplay="true" loop="loop">
<source src="WhiteChristmas.mp3"/>
</audio>
```

This how i am currently reading the audio files from my database using a WebService.

```
 [WebMethod]
    public void PlayXhosa(int id)
    {

        using (The_FactoryDBContext db = new The_FactoryDBContext())
        {
            if (db.Words.FirstOrDefault(word => word.wordID == id).xhosaAudio != null)
            {
                byte[] bytes = db.Words.FirstOrDefault(word => word.wordID == id).xhosaAudio;

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                System.Media.SoundPlayer myPlayer = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(ms);
                myPlayer.Play();
            }
        }

    }
```

This is what my client-side code looks like at the moment

```
function PlayXhosa() {
                var id = $("[id$=hiddenWord_id]").val();
                $.ajax({

                    url: "../../WebService.asmx/PlayXhosa",
                    data: "{ 'id': '" + id + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                    },
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }
                });
            };
```

I then attempt to to call this function like this:

```
 var audio = document.createElement('audio');
 audio.autoplay = false;
 audio.oncanplaythrough = function() {
 foo.disabled = false;
    };
   audio.src = 'PlayXhosa()';
   foo.onclick = function() {
     audio.play();
```

}

Then there is the button.

```
  <button id="foo" disabled>play xhosa audio</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to link a Webservice method to an audio's src element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32345324/how-to-link-a-webservice-method-to-an-audios-src-element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the answer to this question by asking another slighty different but nonetheless  the same question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32904927/5179424

Comment: If this question is a duplicate of the one you've linked, please flag it as a duplicate instead of leaving an answer to that effect. If it is not a duplicate, please leave a complete answer instead of a link-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with your HTML.  Your HTML is still going to reference the location of the media over HTTP.  The difference is that you will write a script that does nothing but output the raw binary data from your database field.

```
<source src="yourScript.aspx?file=WhiteChristmas.mp3" />
```

And then in your script, be sure to set the appropriate headers:

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg");
```

Then, echo out the contents of that field.  You already have your byte array so just use something like `Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)`.

Comment: how would i go about writing the script? im not farmilliar with how to write them. Is it possible for you to show me a demo script. Thanks.

Comment: @LuluthoMgwali I haven't written any C# in a long time, but you would have to show us what ORM you're using and how you're getting your data to begin with.

Comment: @LuluthoMgwali That's your client-side code.  Where's your server-side code?  Add it to your question.

Comment: thats what im currently using, but this only works localy and not when published.. thats why i want to use html5 audio tags.. but all my data is stored in my database

Comment: @LuluthoMgwali I don't understand what you're getting at... you should really show your code.  What you do server-side has nothing to do with how you play that audio client-side.  You can use HTML5 audio tags, but the browser has to get the data from somewhere.  You need a script to send that data from your DB, via HTTP, to the browser.

Comment: yes, that is my question. How do i go about doing that.

Comment: @LuluthoMgwali Show us your code on how you are reading from your database so we can make a meaningful suggestion on how to output the data.

Comment: Do you rate then the client side code will still able to work with the server side code if i do get this right?

Comment: @LuluthoMgwali Yes, you just need to point the audio tag at the URL for the script that returns the stream data.

Comment: Also how would you suggest i write the src element of the code. scr ="PlayAudio()" does not seem rite to me. Have to use PlayAudio.. like in the fiddle i sent becuase i also send the id through with it.

Comment: Can you please have a look at my fiddle again

Comment: @LuluthoMgwali Look at my example again.  You need to set the `src` attribute to the URL of your script.  `audio.src = 'http://example.com/yourScript.aspx'`

Comment: Sorry my bad.. i sent you the incorrect fiddle.. let me edit my question. Sorry @Brad.. Thank you for you patience

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have implemented and it's working perfectly fine. The real hero here is the JS ***fetch*** API.

```js
var url = "http://excample.com/get/bytes"
var audio;
audio = $('audio');

fetch(url, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO'
    }
}).then(response => {
    response.blob()
        .then(blob => {
            const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            audio[0].src = objectUrl;
        }).catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
        })
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```